# Why does a Java program terminates after executing increment operators? In the below code it only prints 2 and not the condition statements?

Tags: java

Consider:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int j = 1;
    int i = 3;
    System.out.println(++j);

    if((j==1) && (i==3)) {
        System.out.println("j is 4 and i is 7");
    }

    if((j==1) || (i==4)) {
        System.out.println("j is 4 or i is 4");

        display();
    }
```

Why does a Java program terminate after executing increment operators? In the below code it only prints 2 and not the condition statements..

Comment: Hi @sarthak basnet and welcome to SO. Could you give us more of the error? It is difficult to interpret what you mean by "prints 2"?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition always comes to false so it is not executed.
You are printing ++j which makes the value of j = 2.

So the program prints 2

Then it checks the condition:

```
If((2==3) && (3==3))
```

The condition returns false so it then checks the next if condition.

```
If ((2==1) || (3==4))
```

This condition also returns false and hence both the *if* statements are not executed.

You need to change the value of j or your *if* condition in order to print the block of code inside the *if* statement.

Therefore, only 2 is printed.